# How do I get the raw dimensions of a bitmap in an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

It seems like I might be overlooking something obvious, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the raw (unscaled) dimensions of a bitmap being displayed in an ImageView.

For example, if I load a bitmap using `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(...)`, I can get those dimensions from `b.getWidth()` and `b.getHeight()`, and I could pass the bitmap into an ImageView using `setImageBitmap(b)`.  But if I have a subclass of ImageView, is there any way to retrieve those dimensions without having to pass them in explicitly?  I guess I'm looking for a `getImageBitmap()` analog of ImageView's `setImageBitmap()` method, which would retrieve a Bitmap object that I can call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on.  Any other way to retrieve the original dimensions would work too, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() command, I think that would do the trick. See SDK documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicHeight%28%29).

Comment: Good, glad to be of service;-)