# Android ImageView get scaled image on screen

Tags: android, image

In my code I'm loading image from source into my ImageView. ScaleType of this image view is FIT_CENTER.
My original image is far bigger than on screen. Is it possible to obtain width and height or scale ratio of image on screen?
I can do it manually like based on orientation of image, calculate ratio of area that ImageView is in and ratio of image itself. After ratio I can assume which dimension is fitted (like width or height) and so on...

Is there any other easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

You can scale your image retaining aspect ratio by setting the adjustViewBound to true and scaleType to fitXY.

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageView's

getDrawable().[getIntrinsicHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicHeight%28%29)

Taken from this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524263/how-do-i-get-the-raw-dimensions-of-a-bitmap-in-an-imageview).

Answer (score 0):

hi set your scale type fitXY
like as this. `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to "auto-scale" your image. You should set the loaded bitmap as background of ImageView control instead of set as source.
Hope this helps.